# Проблема печати на сетевой принтер с сервера Win 2008

Tags: delphi, iis, windows-server, rdp

Исходные данные:

- модуль печати, написанный на Delphi 7, запускается из-под IIS 7.5, на сервере WIN 2008R2
- сетевой принтер  HP P2050(установлен принтером по умолчанию)
- работа идет в терминальной сессии

вылетает по ошибке "Exception EPrinter in module print.exe at 00084612. There is no default printer currently selected. "

Похожие найденные проблемы:

http://www.delphikingdom.com/asp/answer.asp?IDAnswer=55205

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579946/quickreport-throws-there-is-no-default-printer-currently-selected-exception

Задача: обеспечить нормальную работу

"Копать", по идее, можно с 2-х сторон: Delphi и сервер 2008.
Мои раскопки пока ни к чему не привели. Очень нужна помощь.

Добавление: пользователи в терминале подключают и свои принтеры с помощью ScrewDrivers4.
На сервере 2003 все работало.

---

```
CoInitialize(nil); 
ADOQuery1 := TADOQuery.Create(nil); 
Ini := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'Him.ini'); 
ADOQuery1.ConnectionString := Ini.ReadString('Parameters', 'ConnectionString', ''); 
PrinterName := Ini.ReadString('Parameters', 'PrinterName', '');

...

PrinterNotFound := True; 
for i := 0 to printer.Printers.Count - 1 do 
    if Printer.Printers[i] = PrinterName then 
    begin 
        Printer.PrinterIndex := i; 
        PrinterNotFound := False; 
    end;
```

Comment: Дайте немного информации по модулю печати - он использует стандартный TPrinter или что-то стороннее? Что вы уже попробовали со стороны Delphi? В приведенных ссылках мелькает ручная установка индекса нужного принтера, имхо это наименее болезненный вариант.

Comment: begin
  CoInitialize(nil);
  ADOQuery1 := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
  Ini := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'Him.ini');
  ADOQuery1.ConnectionString := Ini.ReadString('Parameters', 'ConnectionString', '');
  PrinterName := Ini.ReadString('Parameters', 'PrinterName', '');  <br/> ...<br/>...<br/>...<br/>PrinterNotFound := True;
  for i := 0 to printer.Printers.Count - 1 do if Printer.Printers[i] = PrinterName then begin
    Printer.PrinterIndex := i;
    PrinterNotFound := False;
  end;

Comment: Дмитрий, не используйте комментарии для дополнений к вопросу. Отредактируйте сам вопрос! =)

Comment: Может стоит посмотреть в сторону permission? Пробуйте из терминала запустить на печать что-нибудь другой программой.